# Is it possible to manipulate data in client side in a jqgrid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have some data in DB(JSON format) which is used to display charts at the same time(one server call) this data is processed to create a table in the jqgrid.

At times, the number of rows in the grid go up to 5000 as a result of which the browser freezes/hangs for some time until the data is processed as it loops 5000 times.

I thought that processing the data one page at a time might solve the problem and when the user requests another page I will handle it in event `onPaging` and use `grid.addRowData()` to display the next set of rows. But while initially defining the grid when only the first set of rows are processed I am unable to find a way to set the total number of pages in the grid, as a result it always shows 1 page and the pagination options are disabled.

There is a parameter which gives the total number of pages `lastpage` but it is a read-only parameter, is there any other way to handle such a case?

Example:

```
            var data; //contains 5000 rows
            var tempData;  //iterate only required number of times on data to get 10 rows
            $('#gridId').jqGrid({datatype : "local",
                        data : tempData,
                       //other parameters,
            onPaging: function(pgButton){//do data handling}
});
```

So in short what I am asking or trying to achieve is to get all of the data on the client side at once and insert it in the jqGrid as and when required by the user, is it possible? I am not able to find any example of this case.

Edit, the code:

```
        var tableData = [];
        var td = {
            tableData : null,
            colNames : [],
            colModel : []
        };

        var table = $("#table");
        //this processing takes aroung 1.38 seconds for a complexity of 5000 for these loops
        var nrOfTp = responseData[0].length;
        for ( var i = 0; i < nrOfTp; i++) {
            for (s in responseData) {

                var data = responseData[s].chartsData;
                //data[i].label are values like "High<br />123"
                var splittedLabel = data[i].label.split("<br />");

                processedResponse.push({
                    beginTP : new timezoneJS.Date(
                            parseFloat(data[i].x),
                            timeZone)
                            .toString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S z"),
                    a : splittedLabel[0],
                    v : data[i].y == "null" ? "-" : splittedLabel[1],
                    p : data[i].y == "null" ? "-" : data[i].y,
                    beginAsTimestamp : data[i].x
                });
            }
            processedResponse.sort(compare);
            processedResponseFinal = processedResponseFinal.concat(processedResponse);
            processedResponse = [];
        }

        td.tableData = processedResponseFinal;

        td.colNames = [ aa.views.tpbegin, aa.al.ap, aa.views.xx, '%', '', ''];
        td.colModel = [ {
            name : 'beginTP',
            index : 'beginTP',
            width : 110,
            sortable : false
        },{
            name : 'a',
            index : 'a',
            width : 80,
            sortable : false
        },{
            name : 'v',
            index : 'v',
            width : 40,
            sortable : false,
            formatter : XXCustomFormatter
        },{
            name : 'p',
            index : 'p',
            width : 35,
            sortable : false,
            formatter : XXCustomFormatter
        },{
            name : 'beginAsTimestamp',
            index : 'beginAsTimestamp',
            width : 145,
            sortable : false,
            hidden: true
        },{
            name : 'edit',
            width : 18,
            sortable : false,
            search : false,
            cellattr: function () { return " title='"+aa.views.al+"'"; },
            formatter : function() {
                return "<span class='ui-icon ui-icon-script'></span>";
            }
        }];

        table.jqGrid({
                datatype : "local",
                data : td.tableData,
                colNames : td.colNames,
                colModel : td.colModel,
                pager : "#pager" + this.options.id,
                pginput : true,
                pgbuttons : true,
                recordtext : "",
                rowNum : 13,
                rowTotal : 13,
                loadComplete : function(data) {
                //some other processing
                }});
```

This is how the responseData looks like:
[image]

Comment: See the docs on [jqGrid site](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html)

Comment: @Max, Hi is there something in particular that I should look for, as I went through it once.

Comment: See Loading Data -> JSON Data. The example show you how to use pagination

Comment: I saw that, but as I mentioned my requirement is little different, I don't have a table in DB for the jqGrid table, I create the data for the jqGrid at client side from some other data and I can't make server calls when the user changes pages. And I cannot process the entire data all at once as this takes a lot of time which hangs the browser.

Comment: @rd22: You wrote "the browser freezes/hangs" if you load 5000 rows at once. How you loaded the data and how you filled the data in the grid? Which `datatype` you use? How you filled the data of the grid? Do you used local paging of data? Which values has `rowNum`? Which version of jqGrid you use and from which fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7)? Could you include more full JavaScript code in the text of your question?

Comment: @rd22 I see docs about jqGrid and I don't find any clue about client side pagination. I suggest you to use an alternative component like [jsGrid](http://js-grid.com) witch has better support for client side pagination

Comment: Hi @Oleg, The problem is not with the jqGrid, I need to create the data which could be used in jqGrid which takes time, iterating the object with 5k+ entries and then creating rows. I get the data to the client by a server call which is in a format my charts expect, then I process this object to pass it to jqGrid `data : td.tableData`. The datatype is `datatype: "local"`. If by local paging you mean the custom inbuilt, then yes I am using it.

Comment: @Oleg The `rowNum` has a dynamic value based on the data, it is usually between 10 to 13. The jqGrid version is ` jqGrid  4.5.2 - jQuery Grid` I suppose it will be the free version.

Comment: @Max Thanks for the info, but I am afraid it will not be possible as jqGrid is alredy integrated in the application at there is lot of red taping involved in getting new compenents. :)

Comment: @oleg would you still like me to include the javascript code?

Comment: @rd22: Yes, the JavaScript code would be interesting to see because I still don't understand why the grid with 5000 rows and small `rowNum` could be so slow. I will have be go away for 1-2 hours, but later I could post you an demo example which use 5000 rows of demo data and will work very quickly. In any way I'd recommend you to update jqGrid to free jqGrid 4.13.3. You can just change the URL to jqGrid files to URLs described [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs). See [code example](http://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html).

Comment: @oleg just posted the code, well somewhat. I would like to make something very clear, it's not the jqGrid which is slow it's the data formatting that is taking the time, well you will see in the code, but what you will not see is when `loadComplete` is called it also does the same amout of iterations on the table data.

Comment: @rd22: Sorry, but the code of from `colModel` and `loadComplete` is the only **real code**, which could do some calculations. The JavaScript code which you posted now don't contain any example of data (at least one row of input data), no definition of columns and no code with "//some other processing". Moreover it's unclear now **when the grid has the performance problem** (on initial loading, on paging, ...). I will just post my answer with the demo, which use 5000 rows, 25 rows per page, 13 columns and display the time in ms for paging, sorting, searching and filtering. It works quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code which you post don't explain the reason of any performance problems which you have. I can only guess that the wrong code in `loadComplete` could be the reason of your problem.

In general jqGrid should process very quickly the data with 5000 rows if you would use not so large page size. The value `rowNum : 13` which you use is small enough. I'd recommend you to use the latest version of [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) (it's version 4.13.3 currently) which you can load directly from CDN (see [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki)). Free jqGrid is the fork of jqGrid which I develop starting with the end of 2014, after renaming it to Guriddo jqGrid JS, making the main for of jqGrid commercial (see [the prices](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334)), changing its license agreement (see [the post](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?p=1438)). I provide free jqGrid under the same conditions (license MIT / GPLv2, for free) like old versions of jqGrid. I use version numbers in the form 4.x.y because I try to hold the compatibility with old 4.x versions jqGrid. I suppose that replacing of 4.5.2 to 4.13.3 will work without any problems. You can still modify the code to use many new options which I implemented in free jqGrid.

**[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/performane-13-5000-25-free-jqgrid.htm)** can be used to see the performance of loading 5000 rows of data with 13 columns and displaying 25 rows of rows per page. You can set filter in some columns, change sorting, use paging and so on. The time of the corresponding operation will be display in the alert.

**UPDATED:** I suspect that the call of `timezoneJS.Date` and the following `.toString`, which you use for filling `beginTP` could be relatively expansive. It could take the most time. I suggest you to consider to fill `data[i].x` directly as the data of `beginTP` column and to use custom formatter, where you use `timezoneJS.Date`. It will dramatically reduce the number of calls of `timezoneJS.Date`: from 5000 to 13 (the page size).

Comment: Thanks for this, I did a test before I start processing my data i.e. from `var nrOfTp = responseData[0].length;` I calculated the time it takes to prepare the `processedResponseFinal` object. Which comes to ~ 1.3s seconds and this is the duration which freezes the browser after this the grid loads very quickly. I will try to put the code here, it's difficult as I am working for a firm. So which brings be back to my original calculation about jgGrid. is it possible to partially load the grid in client side?

Comment: Oh and also, while doing the test I commented the entire code from `loadComplete`.

Comment: I updated the question with the code you asked, has to obscure the variable, I hope they still could make some sense. Please let me know if would like to know something else. And as I said above `loadComplete` does not affect the performance at least not much.

Comment: @rd22: You posted some very strange code fragment for filling the data. It don't contains declaration of many variables, it uses **the same** `i` variable in outer loop `for ( var i = 0; i < nrOfTp; i++) {` and in the inner loop `for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {` which is **definitively wrong** (`var i` in JavaScript will be declared on the function level and non in the loop), the code set `colModel : []` and it's unclear where you change the data, the lines like `data[i].l.split("<br />")` are strange too, .... You don't included any example of the data....

Comment: @rd22: The line with `data[i].l.split("<br />")` is strange because one can suspect that the input data contains **HTML fragments**, which is not so good. The main way of usage jqGrid: usage **pure data** as the input and the usage of [predefined formatters](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:predefined_formatter), [custom formatters](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter), `cellattr`, `rowattr` callbacks and other possibilities to display the data in the format which you need. It allows correctly sort and filter data locally.

Comment: my bad, I mixed the code from two different locations while formatting it to post here. I have corrected it now. Also I have given the example of what `data[i].label` contains. The "<br />" is used as a separator and not as a HTML moreover it nowhere used in the grid directly, as I mentioned earlier it is a data for the charts which is required to be formatted to be displayed in the grid.

Comment: This said, my original problen still holds, will it be possible to feed the data to the grid as and when required from the client side once it has all the data available with it? I hope I am able to make you understand my problem.

Comment: Is there anything else you can share to help me out?

Comment: @rd22: What is your current problem? Is local **paging** is still slowly? Do you have some problem with *initial filling* the grid with data or the grid is slowly on every paging? Is it slowly as my demo? Do you makes the tests with some code inside of `loadComplete`? Do you have the demo online, which I can debug to see the problem?

Comment: Thaks for the reply, The local paging is not an issue. In fact, pagination is not an issue. My issue is my data set is huge and it is not directly in the form the grid can process. The process of making this data valid for the grid takes around 1.38 seconds for a data set of length 5000 objects when the grid is displayed for the first time. When the data is processed(the duration of 1.38 sec) the UI thread hangs/freezes. What I want is a way to pass the data to the grid in chunks when the user demands by pressing the pagination button.

Comment: What I did was used the initial set of rows that I wanted to display in the grid and iterated only that part of the array. This did not take any time and worked as expected. But now when I am passing only say 13 roys to the grid with a `rowNum` of 13. It is not displaying the pagination buttons. For now all I want is to display those buttons with the remaining number of pages so that I can try to fill the grid on `onPaging` event. I don't have this online, I am sorry about that. and I have for now removed the code for `loadComplete` and it does not effect the performance.

Comment: @rd22: Could you post an example of some lines of **original** input data? It's unclear why processing of 5000 rows takes 1.38 sec. You use jqGrid `timezoneJS.Date`, which is unknown for me and it could be the origin of your main performance problem. One can use `data: responseData` and to add `jsonmap` in the columns (see [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/The-usage-of-jsonmap-with-local-data)), which will get the data. One can use `additionalProperties: ["x"]` and remove hidden column `beginAsTimestamp`. There are some possibilities to hold *original data* in the grid.

Comment: I think you nailed it, I never thought this could be the issue. I commented the `timezoneJS.Date` call and it works just fine. Now I need to analyze it why. Just so you know I am using timezone-js which is https://github.com/mde/timezone-js. Thanks a lot. Do you want to add this detail to your answer and then I can accept it. Well this is the least I could do.

Comment: @rd22: You are welcome! I repeat that **I suspect that you probably don't need to use any `timeZone` at all**. `formatter: "date"` can process many formats. It supports `srcformat: "u"` and `srcformat: "u1000"`. You didn't posted any examples of the input data. If you have `data[i].x` as number then it can be good used for sorting. In any way calling of `timezoneJS.Date` on **every item** of the input data seems unneeded for me. You can move the call inside of custom formatter, which will be called **only for the current page** (13 rows). Thus you should have no performance problem.